# websocket not working in spring demo project

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-boot

I want to use web socket in my spring project. I configure the web-socket and calling it from the another controller but some how it's not working. Also i refered the spring doc Visit https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#websocket regularly!
 configuration is:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;


@CrossOrigin
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer  {

    @Override
        public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
            config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
            config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        }

        @Override
        public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/Track").withSockJS();
        }      

}
```

And my controller is where i call and also create some web socket :

```
@Controller
@ComponentScan(value="com.demo.websocket")
public class UserControllerWS {

    @Autowired(required=true)
    private SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserControllerWS.class);

    @MessageMapping("/user")
    @SendToUser("/topic/users")
    public List<User> getUser(
            @Payload UserDto userDto){
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        System.out.println("Event triggerd At User");
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(userDto));
        return null;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/demo",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public void mainTask() {
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
        UserDto userDto=new UserDto();

        this.simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/user", userDto);

        this.simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/users", userDto);


        System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
    }
}
```

Comment: when i call my service main task. i also want to invoke the web-socket  service /topic/user . But i did not invoke. I print some data whenever those web-socket trigger but which is never print after trying all solution.

Answer (score -1):

You need to modify your controller. Just autowire your constructor.

```
@Controller
public class WebSocketController {
    private final SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    WebSocketController(SimpMessagingTemplate template){
        this.template = template;
    }

   @MessageMapping("/send/message")
   public void onRecievedMessage(String message){
      this.template.convertAndSend(
            "/chat",message);
   }
}
```